# How to delete or disable Organization box from UserInfoPage?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Well, as the question says, is there any way to delete or disable organization box?

Here a screenshot:

[image: Organization box]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide both Label and Edit box with [CurPageChanged](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents) procedure in `[Code]` section.

```pascal
[Code]
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin  
  if CurPageID = wpUserInfo then begin  
    WizardForm.UserInfoOrgLabel.Hide();
    WizardForm.UserInfoOrgEdit.Hide();
  end;
end;
```